# Creating bootable Debian image with debootstrap

Tags: debian, boot, bootable, debootstrap

I have been trying to create a bootable debian (jessie/8.4) image for the past 2 days, and as far as I can tell I have the procedure right, but I can not get the filesystem right. I am relatively sure that I am doing something wrong here, missing something with mounting or `/etc/fstab` (*there isn't one in my image*). I was hoping someone with some experience would be able to help me out/show me what I am missing.

Here are the errors I see as I'm booting into qemu-system-x86:

As text and then as the actual screenshots:

## Errors:

```
fsck: error 2 (No such file or directory) while executing fsck.ext2 for /dev/sda1
fsck exited with status code 8
[FAILED] Failed to start Load/Save Random Seed
See `systemctl status systemd-random-seed.service` for details.
[FAILED] Failed to start Various fixups to make systemd work better on Debian.
See `systemctl status debian-fixup.service` for details.
...
[FAILED] Failed to start Update UTMP about System Boot/Shutdown.
See `systemctl status systemd-update-utmp.service` for details.
[DEPEND] Dependency failed for Update UTMP about System Runlevel Changes.
```

[image]
[image]

Here are the instructions I've written up for myself / steps I've taken:

```
cd ~
mkdir debootstrap
cd debootstrap/
# get newest
wget http://ftp.debian.org/debian/pool/main/d/debootstrap/debootstrap_1.0.80_all.deb
ar -x debootstrap_1.0.80_all.deb
zcat /root/debootstrap/data.tar.gz | tar xv

apt-get install parted


# 1.5Gbytes
dd if=/dev/zero of=1445.img bs=1024 count=1 seek=1536k

parted -s 1445.img -- mklabel msdos mkpart primary 1m 1.5g toggle 1 boot
losetup --show -f 1445.img
# prints out `/dev/loopX`, enter this on the next lin
partprobe /dev/loop0
# only have to make the filesytem once --> if you are troubleshooting steps, do not redo this line
mkfs -t ext2 /dev/loop0p1
mount /dev/loop0p1 /mnt

debootstrap --verbose --components=main,contrib,non-free \
--include=firmware-realtek,linux-image-amd64,grub-pc,ssh,vim \
--exclude=nano \
--arch amd64 jessie /mnt http://ftp.us.debian.org/debian
```

[source for information on using --components](http://www.linuxquestions.org/questions/debian-26/how-to-install-debian-using-debootstrap-4175465295/)

- *Ensure that the kernel is installed, it should appear in* `/boot` *within the chroot, that is* `/mnt/boot` *with the following files:*

  - `initrd.img-3.16.0-4-amd64`
  - `vmlinuz-3.16.0-4-amd64`
  - `config-3.16.0-4-amd64`
  - `System.map-3.16.0-4-amd64`
- install grub

  ```
  grub-install --boot-directory=/mnt/boot --modules=part_msdos /dev/loop0
  ```
- Set up APT

  - copy over the apt sources

    ```
    cp /etc/apt/sources.list /mnt/etc/apt/sources.list
    ```
  - ensure the cdrom source is commented out
  - add the line:

    ```
    deb http://ftp.debian.org/debian stable-backports main contrib non-free
    ```

## Setup a chroot

```
mount --bind /dev/pts /mnt/dev/pts
mount --bind /proc /mnt/proc
mount --bind /sys /mnt/sys
mount --bind /dev /mnt/dev

# if you want your pushprofilesettings
cp ~/.bashrc /mnt/root/
cp ~/.vimrc /mnt/root/

# chroot -- enter the system as if it were thy own
chroot /mnt /bin/bash
export HOME=/root
export LC_ALL=C
export LANG=C.UTF-8
export TERM=xterm-256color
```

`mount` *from* [man mount](http://linux.die.net/man/8/mount):
`--bind`    Remount a subtree somewhere else (its contents are available in both places).
`-t <type>` Mount of filesystem *type*, with this, `mount` will attempt to auto determine

## setup serial/console access

edit `/etc/default/grub`:

1. Set `GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX=""` to:

   ```
   GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX="console=tty0 console=ttyS0,115200n8"
   ```
2. Uncomment `GRUB_TERMINAL=console`
3. Beneath, add the line:

   ```
   GRUB_SERIAL_COMMAND="serial --speed=115200 --unit=0 --word=8 --parity=no --stop=1"
   ```

Make the grub config - *This* **MUST** *be done in a non-`systemd-nspawn` shell (that means* `chroot`)

```
grub-mkconfig -o /boot/grub/grub.cfg
```

## Exit chroot

```
exit
```

## Clean up for chroot'ed

```
umount /mnt/sys
umount /mnt/dev
umount /mnt/dev/pts
umount /mnt/proc
```

*Can check for additional mounts with:* `mount | grep /mnt` *and then unmount them with* `umount`

## Enter systemd-nspawn

```
systemd-nspawn -D /mnt
# not you are in a special container
```

**Set the password for `root` with `passwd`**

In `/etc/ssh/sshd_config` comment out `PermitRootLogin without-password` to read `#PermitRootLogin without-password` and insert `PermitRootLogin yes` beneath it

Now enable ssh on startup

```
systemctl enable ssh
```

## clean up

```
# this is needed to clean up both chroot and systemd-nspawn -D /mnt
# once this is run you can not do systemd-nspawn either so wait until you are entirely done
exit
umount /mnt
losetup -d /dev/loop0
```

*Check for additional mounts with:* `mount | grep /mnt` *If* **ANYTHING** *is returned, unmount them with* `umount`

### Recover (only necessary in ERROR)

**If you broke something, or need to retry, RE-MOUNT / SETUP CHROOT on existing** `.img`:

```
losetup --show -f 1445.img
# prints out `/dev/loopX`, enter this on the next lin
partprobe /dev/loop0
mount /dev/loop0p1 /mnt
```

### testing img

```
qemu-system-x86_64 -hda 1445.img -m 1024 -vnc :0
```

Comment: Now probably deleted answer-comment of @505e06b2 : Your "guide" worked wonders for making a Minimal Ubuntu 16 thumbdrive. The only things I changed were the debootstrap and I had to manually get networking working (networkd). My debootstrap line was: `sudo debootstrap --components=main,contrib,nonfree --variant=minbase --include=linux-generic,grub-pc --arch=i386 xenial  /mnt`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Kept at it and figured it out, relatively straight forward from here, but not just a matter of setting up `/etc/fstab`, here is the rest:

**not necessary but a good idea to clean things up**

```
apt-get autoclean
```

**set up `/etc/fstab` - check with `mount` to ensure you are on the right filesystem type**

```
echo "/dev/sda1 / ext4 defaults,errors=remount-ro 0 1" > /etc/fstab
```

**this will rebuild the initramfs and allow it to boot clean**

```
update-initramfs -u -k all
```

Do that and the machine boots clean, tested in QEMU and then I am running it right now on hardware.

Answer (score 6):

**Automated Debian 9 setup without any systemd errors**

This setup does not have any systemd errors or warnings, and I get the Internet connection and a shell at the end.

This setup is just not perfect as I'm not using the Debian kernel, errors when I tried explained in a later section. I then just tried a kernel I had lying around, with config [based on Buildroot](https://github.com/cirosantilli/linux-kernel-module-cheat/tree/8815312cad053d0284c4d91bfbf36a1e9ea207af#find-the-kernel-config) and it worked. The config is provided in this setup. Therefore, it is possible that some packages that rely on missing kernel configs will fail, although I haven't observed any errors so far.

An analogous setup worked perfectly with the Ubuntu kernel however: https://askubuntu.com/questions/281763/is-there-any-prebuilt-qemu-ubuntu-image32bit-online/1081171#1081171 The Ubuntu kernel must have the missing configs compared to the Debian one. The Debian kernel failures can likely be fixed by compiling the Debian kernel with extra options like `CONFIG_VIRTIO_BLK=y` as I've done for Ubuntu.

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

set -eux

debootstrap_dir=debootstrap
root_filesystem=img.ext2.qcow2

sudo apt-get install \
  debootstrap \
  libguestfs-tools \
  git \
  qemu-system-x86 \
;

if [ ! -d "$debootstrap_dir" ]; then
  # Create debootstrap directory.
  # - linux-image-amd64: downloads the kernel image
  sudo debootstrap \
    --include linux-image-amd64 \
    stretch \
    "$debootstrap_dir" \
    http://deb.debian.org/debian/ \
  ;
  sudo rm -f "$root_filesystem"
fi

if [ ! -f "$root_filesystem" ]; then
  # Set root password.
  echo 'root:root' | sudo chroot "$debootstrap_dir" chpasswd

  # Remount root filesystem as rw.
  # Otherwise, systemd shows:
  #     [FAILED] Failed to start Create Volatile Files and Directories.
  # and then this leads to further failures in the network setup.
  cat << EOF | sudo tee "${debootstrap_dir}/etc/fstab"
/dev/sda / ext4 errors=remount-ro,acl 0 1
EOF

  # Network.
  # We use enp0s3 because the kernel boot prints:
  #     8139cp 0000:00:03.0 enp0s3: renamed from eth0
  # This can also be observed with:
  #     ip link show
  # Without this, systemd shows many network errors, the first of which is:
  #     [FAILED] Failed to start Network Time Synchronization.
  cat << EOF | sudo tee "${debootstrap_dir}/etc/network/interfaces.d/00mytest"
auto lo
iface lo inet loopback
auto enp0s3
iface enp0s3 inet dhcp
EOF

  # Generate image file from debootstrap directory.
  # Leave 1Gb extra empty space in the image.
  sudo virt-make-fs \
    --format qcow2 \
    --size +1G \
    --type ext2 \
    "$debootstrap_dir" \
    "$root_filesystem" \
  ;
  sudo chmod 666 "$root_filesystem"
fi

# linux_image="$(printf "${debootstrap_dir}/boot/vmlinuz-"*)"

linux_img=linux/arch/x86_64/boot/bzImage
if [ ! -f "$linux_img" ]; then
  # Build the Linux kernel.
  git clone --depth 1 --branch v4.18 git://git.kernel.org/pub/scm/linux/kernel/git/stable/linux.git
  cd linux
  wget https://gist.githubusercontent.com/cirosantilli/6e2f4975c1929162a86be09f839874ca/raw/6d151d231a233408a6e1b541bf4a92fd55bf5338/.config
  make olddefconfig
  make -j`nproc`
  cd -
fi

qemu-system-x86_64 \
  -append 'console=ttyS0 root=/dev/sda' \
  -drive "file=${root_filesystem},format=qcow2" \
  -enable-kvm \
  -serial mon:stdio \
  -m 2G \
  -kernel "$linux_img" \
  -device rtl8139,netdev=net0 \
  -netdev user,id=net0 \
;
```

[GitHub upstream](https://github.com/cirosantilli/linux-cheat/blob/4a15040fdc75844d869a46d1e4c5389f17502544/debootstrap-debian-qemu.sh).

Now from the terminal, login with `root` / `root`, and then check that the Internet works with the following commands:

```
printf 'GET / HTTP/1.1\r\nHost: example.com\r\n\r\n' | nc example.com 80
apt-get update
apt-get install hello
hello
```

We used `nc` as explained at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32341518/how-to-make-an-http-get-request-manually-with-netcat/52662497#52662497 because:

- `wget` and `curl` are not installed by default
- `ping` does not work from QEMU by default: [How to ping from the QEMU guest to an external URL?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/473448/how-to-ping-from-the-qemu-guest-to-an-external-url)

Tested on an Ubuntu 18.04 host.

**What happens if I try to use the Debian kernel**

TODO understand and fix. If I replace the Linux kernel compilation above with the Debian packaged Linux kernel:

```
linux_img="${debootstrap_dir}/boot/vmlinuz-"*
```

then boot fails with:

```
Kernel panic - not syncing: VFS: Unable to mount root fs on unknown-block(0,0)
```

and an empty list for:

```
List of all partitions:
```

so the disk is not being recognized at all. I've also tried to use the exact same kernel that the Debian ISO installer installs [as done here but for Debian](https://askubuntu.com/questions/884534/how-to-run-ubuntu-16-04-desktop-on-qemu/1046792#1046792), and it fails in the same way, even though the Debian ISO install worked fine with the same QEMU options (it generates GRUB install in a disk with multiple partitions, the root one being `ext4`).

Comment: If anyone is doing this on a fresh Ubuntu install, you also need to install `build-essentials` before running the script. You will be missing `git`, `make`, `bison` & `flex`

Also be aware there is a link in here to OP github config, you might want to read it through before running it blindly to make sure it hasn't changed.

Answer (score 4):

Can't comment, but your "guide" worked wonders for making a Minimal Ubuntu 16 thumbdrive. The only things I changed were the debootstrap and I had to manually get networking working (`networkd`).

My debootstrap line was:

```
#> sudo debootstrap --components=main,contrib,nonfree  --variant=minbase \
                    --include=linux-generic,grub-pc --arch=i386 xenial /mnt
```

Comment: If you can *validate* this guide, then write 4-5 answers ASAP, get your around 50 rep, and then you will be able to comment it. I don't flag your post for deletion, because it is too worthy, but I should, because it is really not an answer. Thus, others will likely do. *But you can get that 50 rep very soon.* Answer 3-4 trivial questions and tomorrow you will have...

Comment: We have a lot of beginner Linuxers here, helping them is an easy way to a rocket-like rep boost. Other SE sites aren't so easy.