# Failed to start Create Volatile Files and Directories in Debian

Tags: linux, debian, beagleboneblack

Using debian in beaglebone black. The board is connected online with a static ip for remote ssh. After few days I couldn't able to ssh my board. While debugging the board received following error log.

```
Failed to start Create Volatile Files and Directories.
```

Failed services:   Volatile file creation, ssh-server, networking service etc. Failed to start.

What may be went wrong ? Have anyone faced similar issue.

Log:

```
[FAILED] Failed to start Create Volatile Files and Directories
[FAILED] Failed to start Entropy daemon using the HAVEGE algorithm    
[FAILED] Failed to start Network Time Synchronization.    
[FAILED] Failed to start The Apache HTTP Server.

**[FAILED] Failed to start OpenBSD Secure Shell server.**
```

Comment: That's not your log.  That's what's printed to your console.  Look at, and show people, your actual journal.

Comment: Do you have `rng-tools5` installed for entropy?

Answer (score 0):

**Make sure that the root filesystem is `rw`**

I had this problem when I was trying to create a `debootstrap` image that works on QEMU.

After some Googling on random forums, I found that the solution is to make the root filesystem read-write, instead of the default read-only that the Linux kernel mounts it as.

The most correct way to do that in Debian is to add to your `fstab`:

```
/dev/sda / ext4 errors=remount-ro,acl 0 1
```

which remounts the root with the default `rw` parameter, although I haven't tested it yet.

The root problem with `debootstrap` is that the `fstab` is just a dummy as explained at: https://askubuntu.com/questions/557556/why-is-my-etc-fstab-file-unconfigured/1080541#1080541

An alternative that might work would be to pass the `rw` kernel boot parameter, but I haven't tested it in Debian, [only Buildroot](https://github.com/cirosantilli/linux-kernel-module-cheat/tree/1813b7bb569e5b0c689aa33386a99accbd1b0885#rw).

The final working `debootstrap` setup I achieved is described at: [Creating bootable Debian image with debootstrap](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/275429/creating-bootable-debian-image-with-debootstrap/473256#473256)